# Django ModelForm Hidden Field to 'True' in only a certain situation?

Tags: python, html, django, django-forms

I've got the following Django Form; it has a field called 'finished', that is hidden.  I set the default to False because there is only *one* situation where I want it set to True.

The problem is that it still marks it as "False" and I can't figure out how to change it in that one situation.

In my `views.py` I have this:

```
        context["test_form"] = TestForm(
            instance=self.object, hide_status=True, is_finished=True
        )
```

the `form` looks like this:

```
class TestForm(ModelForm):
    finished = forms.BooleanField(
        widget=forms.HiddenInput(), initial=False, required=False
    )
    status = forms.Select(attrs={"class": "form-control"})

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        hide_status = kwargs.pop("hide_status", None)
        is_finished = kwargs.pop("is_finished", None)
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields["status"].queryset = Status.objects.filter(active=True)
        self.fields["status"].widget.attrs["class"] = "form-control"
        if hide_status:
            self.fields["status"].widget = HiddenInput()
        if is_finished:
            self.fields["finished"].initial = True

    class Meta:
        model = Test
        fields = ["finished", "status"]
```

The HTML is super simple:

```
<form method="post" action="{% url 'my_app:test-update' %}">
{% csrf_token %}
{{ test_form.as_p }}
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Finish</button>
</form>
```

The rendered HTML looks like this:

```
<input type="hidden" name="finished" value="False" id="id_finished">
```

What is the best way to get that set to True in this case?